# mongoDB DuplicateKey error is undefined when trying to insert a duplicated email

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created many error handlers in order to handle MongoDB errors, one of them is this which is for duplicated data :

```
const dbDuplicateKeyHandler = (error) => {
  console.log(error);   
  
  console.log(error.keyPattern.name);
  
  // const message = `Duplicated field value: (${error.keyValue.name}) Please use another value .`;
  
  return new AppError(400, `Duplicated field value: (${error.keyValue.name}) Please use another value .`);
```

the problem is, when I try to insert a duplicated username the error message is printed as I want it to be, but in case I'm trying with a new user name but duplicated email the `error.keyValue.name` will be `undefined`. The handler was working correctly in Postman when I was building the API. also I've searched for the Doc that explain mongoDB errors but couldn't find any.
I console logging the error in both cases

```
console.log("THE ERROR IS ==>",error);   
console.log("error.keyPattern.name IS ==> ",error.keyPattern.name);
console.log("error.keyValue.name IS ==> ",error.keyValue.name);
```

For duplicated username:

[image]

for duplicated email :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of email you are using:

```js
error.keyPattern.name
error.keyValue.name
```

But it should be:

```js
error.keyPattern.email
error.keyValue.email
```

You are getting `undefined` because there is no property of `keyPattern` or `keyValue` with a name `name`.

For consistency instead of `error.keyValue.name` or `error.keyValue.email` you could just do:

```
console.log("error.keyPattern IS ==> ", Object.entries(error.keyPattern)[0]);
console.log("error.keyValue IS ==> ", Object.entries(error.keyValue)[0]);

//Prints
error.keyPattern IS ==> ["name", 1]
error.keyValue IS ==> ["name", "username"]

error.keyPattern IS ==> ["email", 1]
error.keyValue IS ==> ["email", "username@example.com"]
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I used `${Object.values(error.keyValue)[0]}` to get the value entered by the user

Comment: Excellent option. Good luck with your project.